# "authentication methods aren't supported by server" on Android devices

Tags: plesk, sasl, postfix-mta

I have this error "authentication methods aren't supported by server" when i try to configure SMTP in an android device. In ios it works perfectly using MD5 Challenge. 
I tried to enable CRAM-MD5, DIGEST and LOGIN but it still gives me that error.

I tested every port available. I´m using Plesk 12 with Postfix and Dovecot.

Comment: Don't see this issue with GMail 6.10.23.137993986 it can successfully authorize with dovecot's IMAP/POP3 and postfix SMTP(ports 25 and 587). Which app you are using?

Comment: The default Mail app included in android. Even the Gmail App fails.

Answer (score 0):

After a research i´ve found that my Postfix configuration was blocking plain login in postfix/main.cf with the parameter:

```
`smtpd_sasl_security_options= noplaintext`
```

I think this should be a standard to prevent man in the middle attacks.
Plain text should be only used in combination with TLS/SSL cipher.